# How to disable sound effect of deleting files in Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki?

Tags: release-loki, settings, pantheon-files, sound

When deleting a file it plays a paper crunching sound. I keep my Desktop volume at max and adjust in-app sounds. This paper crunching sound is really loud when earphones are plugged in. 
How can I disable or reduce its volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Settings > Sound Settings > Sound Effects > Mute;

Comment: No longer a 'Sound Effects' option in latest?